# How to formulate a hyperlink in OpenDocument/ OpenOffice Calc

Tags: hyperlink, openoffice-calc

I am using Open Office Calc and trying to create a link to another worksheet but using the HYPERLINK formula function.

For some reason the following won't work and I cannot find the solution anywhere on the web.

`=HYPERLINK(#New.A1,'new')` and I've also tried `=HYPERLINK(#New.A1;'new')`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes.

```
=HYPERLINK("#New.A1"; "new")
```

There is an example at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#HYPERLINK.

Comment: Ah the key difference to your answer is the , - for Open Office it should be a ; but apart from that great link and answer. I've plus 1+ it but not the answer if you're happy to amend.

Comment: Okay, I made the change as requested.  However a comma may work for other people who look at this post, and it was not clear from the question what application and version you have (perhaps Apache OpenOffice 4.1.3?).  Since it helped you find the solution, it would probably have made sense to accept the original answer anyway and then add the comment.